# Correct positioning of right-hand superscript in combination with \underbrace

Tags: math-mode, superscripts

I have a term that needs both an underbrace and a transpose sign as a superscript on its right side. There are three options in what order the `\underbrace` command its corresponding subscript and the superscript can be coded. Unfortunately, none of the possible combinations yields the correct typographic result. See the MWE for details:

[image]

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\newcommand{\Tr}{\ensuremath{\mathsf{T}}}

\begin{document}

Correct spacing without \verb!\underbrace!:
\begin{equation}
( a - b )^{\Tr}
\end{equation}

With \verb!\underbrace! and correct positioning of the \verb!\Tr!-symbol, but
actually the brace is supposed to embrace the inner term only:
\begin{equation}
\underbrace{( a - b )^{\Tr}}_{{} = c}
\end{equation}

The \verb!\underbrace! includes the correct part of the term, but the
\verb!\Tr!-symbol is now misplaced above the term
\begin{equation}
\underbrace{( a - b )}_{{} = c}^{\Tr}
\end{equation}

With an additional pair of \verb!{}! the result is nearly correct, but the
\verb!\Tr!-symbol is placed too high in comparison without any
\verb!\underbrace!:
\begin{equation}
{\underbrace{( a - b )}_{{} = c}}^{\Tr}
\end{equation}

The latter is visually disturbing if there is a mixed sequence of terms
with and without \verb!\underbrace! and varying height of the
\verb!\Tr!-symbol:
\begin{equation}
( a - b )^{\Tr} {\underbrace{( c - d )}_{{} = c}}^{\Tr} ( e - f )^{\Tr}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put an empty `{}` in front like `{}^{\Tr}`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\newcommand{\Tr}{\mathsf{T}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
( a - b )^{\Tr} {\underbrace{( c - d )}_{= c}}{}^{\Tr} ( e - f )^{\Tr}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I accepted this answer as correct because it works without any additional package. But actually I use the other suggested solution (with `mathtools`) because I have this package loaded anyway for another purpose. What I really like more about the other answer is that the nesting of the braces reflects the logical structure. Here - in this answer - the `\Tr`-symbol is the right-hand superscript of an invisible atom and not related to its original base term. But as I said, I like the solution for its simplicity.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you use the `\cramped` macro, which is provided by the `mathtools` package, for this job. The left-hand term, without the underbrace, has the transpose signal at the desired height. The middle term features the transpose symbol in a position that's slightly too elevated. Using `\cramped`, as is shown on the right, achieves your objective.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern,mathtools}
\newcommand{\Tr}{\mathsf{T}}
\begin{document}
\[
( a - b )^{\Tr} \text{ vs }
{\underbrace{( a - b )}_{{} = c}}^{\Tr} \text{ vs }
\cramped{\underbrace{( a - b )}_{{} = c}}^{\Tr}
\]
\end{document}
```